# the rule of S V O C and S V O O

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I learned that two of the sentence patterns are **S V O C** and **S V O O**,
the verbs in these patterns would be different from other verbs, meaning they would have their own grammar rules.

What if I use these kinds of **verbs** in a way that does not fall into the two mentioned structures, say, I put these kinds of verbs in a gerund form or a infinitive form?

Do the rules still apply?

These verbs still have to be followed by ***object + complement or indirect object + direct object*** ?

For example,

Infintive form:

> The soldiers have no desire **to keep the citizens safe**.
>
> The students aren't willing **to give others their textbooks**.

Gerund form:

> The soldiers are tired **of keeping the citizens safe**.
>
> The teacher never took an interest **in reading the students a story**.

These are some sentences I wrote, they don't seem to fit into S V O C and S V O O patterns,
but are the sentences still grammatical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples you give are all grammatically correct.

In the non-finite clauses the verbs don't have subjects, but there is still the VOC or VOO order, and the meaning is of the syntax is the same as for a finite clause.